# What is the Facebook Business Manager "BUSINESS_SCOPED_USER_ID"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As usual the official FB documentation is confusing..
Literally:

> You need:
>
> adaccount_id : the ad account id (in "act_123" form)
>
> user_id : the id
>
> of the user to add the role to assign Make this POST call to add a new
>   user as Admin:

```
curl \
-F "user=BUSINESS_SCOPED_USER_ID" \
-F "role=ADMIN" \
-F "access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/VERSION/act_AD_ACCOUNT_ID/assigned_users"
```

Ok! so what's the **BUSINESS_SCOPED_USER_ID**!?
I advance one of your possible answers..ain't your user ID..

The error?

```
  'error_user_title' => string 'User is not Business Scoped'
  'error_user_msg' => string 'The user ID provided is not business scoped. Please provide a business or a system user ID'
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business "A business may operate several Facebook Apps or bots - common in games studios, for example, to support use cases such as cross-promotion or fraud detection, or in bots used to communicate with users. In these cases, you may need to map the same person's ID between those apps and bots."

Answer (score 0):

A user have a generic userId, and several scoped userIds, one per application, page, business he's associated with.

Here, you need to use the id that the user has inside the business the AdAccount belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `{user-id}/business_users` edge (I'm using it with v4.0): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/business_users/

I'm using an app-scoped user ID and it returns an array of items like:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "{business_scoped_id}",
      "name": "{user_name}",
      "business": {
        "id": "{business_id}",
        "name": "{business_name}"
      }
    },
    ...
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "",
      "after": ""
    }
  }
}
```

When you're hitting the `act_{account_id}/assigned_users` edge, you will also need to specify a `business` parameter which is the `business_id`.

Hope that helps!